# Browser Storage

Tags: javascript

Подскажите, пожалуйста возможно ли добавить запись в localStorage или sessionStorage браузера для другого сайта, спасибо.

Comment: разве что в самописном браузере. иначе подобные идеи со здравым смыслом несколько не в ладах

Answer (score 0):

Политика безопасности не позволит, так что нельзя